# Get elements of HTML TR when a button in the row is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-delegate

I have the following ***Dynamic***  HTML row.

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
     <td contenteditable="false" class="sorting_1"> </td>
     <td contenteditable="false"> <span class="name">Alex Nilson </span></td>
     <td contenteditable="false"><span class="price"> 1234 </span></td>
     <td contenteditable="false"> <span class="qty" >1234 </span></td>
     <td><button class="pr_edit" href="javascript:;"> Edit </button></td>
     <td><button class="pr_elete" href="javascript:;"> Delete </button></td>
</tr>
```

When the edit button is clicked, I need to get the values of the cell elements of that particular row into jQuery, as JS variables, that I can AJAX POST to another PHP page to insert into database. I tried to do it like the following, but it didn't pan out.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.pr_edit').click(function () {
         var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find('td');            
         $.each(currentTD, function () {
             var iname = $(this).find("span.name").html();
             var iprice = $(this).find("span.price").val();
             var iqty=$(this).find("span.qty").val();
         });
```

It doesn't catch the variables as I intended.How do I achieve this? I need to get these SPAN data to three variables.

Comment: What is the `currentTD` variable for? Where is it defined?

Comment: `$('table').on('click', '.pr_edit', function () {` use event delegation technique for dynamic elements.

Comment: @mikeyq6: Updated the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need event [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated elements and use `text()` instead of `val()` to get the content of `span`. Also use `closest('tr')` to get parent `tr`, you don't need to use each.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('body').on('click', '.pr_edit', function () {
         var currentTR = $(this).closest('tr');
         var iname = currentTR.find("span.name").text();
         var iprice = currentTR.find("span.price").text();
         var iqty = currentTR.find("span.qty").text();
     });
 });
```

Comment: First time seeing `.closest('tr');` . Awesome One Azim. `:)`

Comment: @Azim: I need to get the value of the class="sorting_1" class also. It is a row number set by CSS counter method. I cant get it by normal methods like var sl = $(this).closest('tr').find("span.sl").text();

Comment: I didn't asked question. Question is asked by @AkhilKPAULOSE.

Comment: Oh sorry. @NanaPartykar

Comment: In your given html there is no `span` with class `sl`. @AkhilKPAULOSE

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with dynamic data and jQuery, you need to bind your click-event dynamically to.
instead :

```
$('.pr_edit').click(function () {
    //magic
}
```

do

```
$('.pr_edit').on('click', function () {
    //magic
}
```

but if even your whole table is being loaded dynamically, you have to have an element thats "allways" there as a reference. like:

```
$('html, body').on('click', '.pr_edit', function () {
  //magic
}
```

Check this out for refference: http://api.jquery.com/on/